# Linux - How to find files changed in last 12 hours without find command

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find files modified in the last 12 hours. However, the directory is quite large so using the usual find command takes way too long.

Anyone have any ideas doing this quicker? I was thinking something like listing the files, then using head to get the top 20 and then check those files only. But I'm not sure.

Any help?

UPDATE: Thanks to the help of the chosen answer, we have figured out that you can actually find a file without using the find command. The trick is to timestamp the file names, then use the following code to get the latest one:

`ls -1 /directory/files*.txt | sort -nr | head -1`

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: I wrote it out, but Marki555 got what I was trying to say, something like `ls . | head -20 | find -mtime`

Comment: No. Nothing you whip up in bash could possibly work any faster than `find`. The only way to really address the problem is to reduce the number of files you have to look at.

Comment: @Sammitch I just updated the question to show how we figured it out. It is indeed faster than the find command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file modification time is stored in its inode. So whatever command you use has to read inodes for all files in that directory. You can make your own script for checking the mtime, but it won't be faster.

Listing the directory contents (filenames only) is really fast, try with `ls -1` (*ls minus one*).But listing it with file attributes like mtime is slow: `ls -l` (*ls minus little L*).

The file list in directory is read in "random" order by the filesystem (the order depends on many things, but is static). So you can't use something like stopping after X number of files. `ls -t` lists the files sorted by mtime, but it has to read the mtime of all files in order to sort them.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. I guess the fastest way might be to just move older files out of that directory daily/weekly? I really thought there was a better way than that :-/

Comment: Best approach is not to have too files there... Use subdirs for each day or month and create the files there... if that is not possible, make a symlink (e.g. `current`) pointing to the current date-dir and each day change it point to a new directory.

Comment: Okay wait, @Marki555, you just made a great point. If the ls -1 (minus one) is a lot faster, the file names are actually timestamped so I could just do the following: `ls -1 /directory | sort -nr | head -20 | find -mtime 0.25` and it should work a lot faster :-) ....In short, timestamp the file name, list it, sort it, head and then find. Nice teamwork.